# Webpack3 import bootstrap and other libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I´m using Angular 5 && Electron && Webpack.
 I had to eject my angular project to add some nodejs modules like fs or net and it creates a file named webpack.config.js by default.
I want to render Bootstrap(js && css), jQuery && Poper.js

That are my entry points

```
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","styles", "scripts","vendor","main"];
```

That are my definition of bundles

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css",
    "./src\\styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "./node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.min.js",
    "./node_modules\\popper.js\\dist\\umd\\popper.min.js",
    "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

I never get render this files, so I cant use it

I only get render styles.css that is in that path specified above.

I have a lot of rules that I dont understand and I think that is there where I have to put my references to my files

```
    "module": {
        "rules": [
          {
            "test": /\.html$/,
            "loader": "raw-loader"
          },
          {
            "test": /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
            "loader": "file-loader",
            "options": {
              "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
              "limit": 10000
            }
          },
          {
            "test": /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
            "loader": "url-loader",
            "options": {
              "name": "[name].[hash:20].[ext]",
              "limit": 10000
            }
          },
          {
            "exclude": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.css$/,
            "use": [
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "exclude": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
            "use": [
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "sass-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true,
                  "precision": 8,
                  "includePaths": []
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "exclude": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.less$/,
            "use": [
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "less-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "exclude": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.styl$/,
            "use": [
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "stylus-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true,
                  "paths": []
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "include": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.css$/,
            "use": [
              "style-loader",
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "include": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
            "use": [
              "style-loader",
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "sass-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true,
                  "precision": 8,
                  "includePaths": []
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "include": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.less$/,
            "use": [
              "style-loader",
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "less-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "include": [
              path.join(process.cwd(), "../node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.min.css"),
              path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
            ],
            "test": /\.styl$/,
            "use": [
              "style-loader",
              {
                "loader": "raw-loader"
              },
              {
                "loader": "postcss-loader",
                "options": {
                  "ident": "embedded",
                  "plugins": postcssPlugins,
                  "sourceMap": true
                }
              },
              {
                "loader": "stylus-loader",
                "options": {
                  "sourceMap": true,
                  "paths": []
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "test": /\.ts$/,
            "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
          }
        ]
      },
      "plugins": [
        new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            "context": "src",
            "to": "",
            "from": {
              "glob": "assets\\**\\*",
              "dot": true
            }
          },
          {
            "context": "src",
            "to": "",
            "from": {
              "glob": "favicon.ico",
              "dot": true
            }
          }
        ], {
          "ignore": [
            ".gitkeep",
            "**/.DS_Store",
            "**/Thumbs.db"
          ],
          "debug": "warning"
        }),
        new ProgressPlugin(),
        new CircularDependencyPlugin({
          "exclude": /(\\|\/)node_modules(\\|\/)/,
          "failOnError": false,
          "onDetected": false,
          "cwd": projectRoot
        }),
        new NamedLazyChunksWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          "template": "./src\\index.html",
          "filename": "./index.html",
          "hash": false,
          "inject": true,
          "compile": true,
          "favicon": false,
          "minify": false,
          "cache": true,
          "showErrors": true,
          "chunks": "all",
          "excludeChunks": [],
          "title": "Webpack App",
          "xhtml": true,
          "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
            let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
            let rightIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
            if (leftIndex > rightIndex) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (leftIndex  {
                    return module.resource
                        && (module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules)
                            || module.resource.startsWith(genDirNodeModules)
                            || module.resource.startsWith(realNodeModules));
                },
          "chunks": [
            "main"
          ]
        }),
        new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
          "filename": "[file].map[query]",
          "moduleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]",
          "fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate": "[resource-path]?[hash]",
          "sourceRoot": "webpack:///"
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
          "name": [
            "main"
          ],
          "minChunks": 2,
          "async": "common"
        }),
        new NamedModulesPlugin({}),
        new AngularCompilerPlugin({
          "mainPath": "main.ts",
          "platform": 0,
          "hostReplacementPaths": {
            "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
          },
          "sourceMap": true,
          "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
          "skipCodeGeneration": true,
          "compilerOptions": {}
        })
      ],
      "node": {
        "fs": "empty",
        "global": true,
        "crypto": "empty",
        "tls": "empty",
        "net": "empty",
        "process": true,
        "module": false,
        "clearImmediate": false,
        "setImmediate": false
      },
      "externals": {
        "electron": "require('electron')",
        "fs": "require('fs')",
        "mongodb": "require('mongodb')",
        "crypto": "require('crypto')",
        "net": "require('net')",
        "module": "require('module')"
      },
      "devServer": {
        "historyApiFallback": true
      }
    };
```

Comment: are you getting error message?

Comment: no, no error is displayed, all work fine except that not render nothing except styles.css

Comment: can you put sample to https://stackblitz.com or https://github.com ? Its hard to trace if look snippet code